# Почему картинки не отображаются в Django?

Tags: django

```
urls.py:

urlpatterns = [
        ...
        path('main/', views.main ,name = 'main'),

]

views.py:

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'site/index.html')

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href='style.css'>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap&subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Дорогами нашей победы!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <style>
        body{
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;

}
a{
    text-decoration: none;

}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.header{
    height: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    background:url(img/2x/1.png)center no-repeat;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-size: 100%;


}
.img-block{
  width: 1349px;
  height: 843px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.img-block__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s time;
  -o-transition: all .5s time;
  transition: all .5s time;
}
.img-block:hover .img-block__text{
    opacity: 1;
}
.links{
  color: #565F5C;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 45px;
}
button{
width: 800px;
height: 60px;
font-size: 50px;
}
    </style>
    <div class="header">
        <h1 align="center">Стоит помнить!<h1>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
    <button><a href="#">Написать свою историю</a></button>
    <button><a href="#">Вспомним всех поимённо</a></button>
    <button><a href="#">Историческая справка</a></button>
  </div>
    <div class="img-block">
      <img src="img/10.jpg" alt="Фото не найдено!">
      <span class="img-block__text">
      У каждого из нас есть родственники, которые участвовали в Великой Отечественной войне.В канун семьдесят пятой годовщины, как никогда, стоит рассказать о подвиге, совершённом вашими предками
      </span><br>
  </div>   


</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Где находятся изображения и каким образом Вы пытаетесь их раздавать? Средствами `Django` или сервером (например, `Nginx`)?

Comment: Средствами Django

Answer (score 1):

в setting.py

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

и в хедере страницы

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
```

статические файлы в настройках подключаешь

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @jadesheart картинки так  <img src="{%static 'logo.png' %}" class="logo">
к примеру лого скинул